# groovy markup java.lang.Exception: No method named issue

Tags: groovy, markupbuilder

Good day.

I am working on this groovy script

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder;
import groovy.xml.*;

def writer = new StringWriter();
def xmlResponse = new MarkupBuilder(writer);
def index = 0;

xmlResponse.CalculatePayoutFigureResponse() {
    Identifier([UniqueID:'CalculatedLoanRepayment-1'])
}
String response =  writer.toString();
return XmlUtil.serialize(response);
```

Every time this gets called, I am getting the ff error:

```
    SEVERE: java.lang.Exception: No method named 'Identifier' found for arguments [[UniqueID:CalculatedLoanRepayment-1]]
java.lang.Exception: No method named 'Identifier' found for arguments [[UniqueID:CalculatedLoanRepayment-1]]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:74)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
```

Anyone familiar with this? Can you point me to the correct direction.

I have been looking for solutions but to no avail. Is the way I am building the XML wrong? I am using groovy 2.4.4.

THanks in advance! 
Chris

Comment: After posting what I thought was a solution, I eventually just ran your sample code locally, and it works fine in both groovy 2.4.3 and 2.4.4, so I am unsure why you're getting an issue. As you found, you can prefix the element with the builder object, but if it is as you have posted you shouldn't need to do that in the code you've posted. Still if it works for you, so be it.

Comment: Yup, I myself is not convinced with the solution but will stick with it for now. Thanks for the help Mark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some tweaks to the code, I was able to make this work. I used the MarkupBuilder object before every element I am trying to add. Code became like this:

```
xmlResponse.CalculatePayoutFigureResponse() {
    xmlResponse.Identifier(UniqueID:'CalculatedLoanRepayment-1')
}
```

I got the output that I expected.

```
<CalculatePayoutFigureResponse>
   <Identifier UniqueID='CalculatedLoanRepayment-1' />
</CalculatePayoutFigureResponse>
```

No idea though as to why this solution worked and what caused the issue I initially encountered.

Thanks!
-Chris

Comment: I double checked your original code, and I was actually wrong when I said the map needs to be expanded, that's just how I'd learned how to do it. I actually can't get your original code to fail as it is, so not sure what's going on here. Glad adding the builder in front of the element name worked. You could try one more thing for my sanity and just quote the element, so use `"Identifier"` instead of `Identifier`. Also, is this code part of something bigger? I notice you're doing a return at the end which hints the code is a sample?